# .htaccess - basic URL rewrite with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am new to URL rewriting using ".htaccess" file. I have a problem with replacing query string after "search" in the URL. I am using MVC format to develop my website and the word, "search", in the URL is one of the methods that can be called in "Dictionary" controller.

This is what I want to get:

```
 http://localhost/mvcWeb/dictionary/search/good
```

And this is what I get from the URL:

```
http://localhost/mvcWeb/dictionary/search?dictionary=good
```

This is all I have in my ".htaccess" file:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Please help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: there is a youtube url where you can do this. try researching

Comment: https://www.addedbytes.com/articles/for-beginners/url-rewriting-for-beginners/

Comment: The last rule should look something like this: RewriteRule (.+)\?dictionary=(.+)$ $1/$2 [L]